# How to select distinct records based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have table of duplicate records like [image]
Now I want only one record from duplicate records which has latest created date as [image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problem do you run into exactly?

Answer (score 3):

use `row_number()`:

```
select EnquiryId, Name, . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by enquiryID order by CreatedDate desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ROW_NUMBER function to tag the duplicate records ordered by CreatedDate, like this:

```
;with CTE AS (
    select *, row_NUMBER() over(
                 partition by EnquiryID -- add columns on which you want to identify duplicates
                 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) as rn
    FROM TABLE 
)
select * from CTE
where rn = 1
```