# Excluding fields while using Over() function in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am using a `count(field_name) Over(partition by field_name)` function in sql and wanted to only show the values greater than 1. I found that I cannot use an aggregate function in the where or having clause and was hoping there was another way, short of writing a function as I do not have write privileges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: use an inline view or Common table expression (with clause) [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26484634/119477) has answers with both techniques

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` excludes `null`s, so instead of counting the column itself, you can add some logic there by introducing a `case` expression:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN field_name > 1 THEN field_name ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY field_name) f
```

EDIT:
I seem to have misunderstood the original question. If you want to filter out the results of the `count` function, you'll need a subquery:

```
SELECT office, cnt
FROM   (SELECT office, COUNT(office) OVER(PARTITION BY office) cnt
        FROM   my_table)
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

Comment: This technique would work but the count field is a string that includes numbers and letters. The query failed when converting some strings to ints.

Comment: I guess an alternative : `SUM(CASE WHEN field_name > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: So can you elaborate on "I wanted to only show the values greater than 1" - I must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: My apologies. I am using the count(office) Over(partition by office) to count how many times a particular office appears in the query then ordering by that count. I was hoping to only display the information where the office count is greater than 1